# Loading a preview of a website in a `UIImageView` (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nsurlrequest

I'm attempting to load a preview of a website into a `UIImageView`. I have the following method that is called when the requested website url is received:

```
func loadWebsite(item:ShareItem) {
    activitySpinner.startAnimating()
    imageView.setImageForURL(item.asset!.absoluteString) { (image) in
        self.showActionButton(true)
        self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
        self.actionButton.titleLabel?.text = "Open"
    }
}
```

I believe there's an error in my logic in the `setImageForURL` website, which is what is supposed to load the website into my custom image view class:

```
class MyCustomImageView:UIImageView, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var webview:UIWebView?
    var completion:((UIImage?)->Void)?

    func setImageForURL(urlString:String, completion:((image:UIImage?)->Void)?) {

        self.completion = completion

        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else {
            self.completion?(nil)
            return
        }

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webview = UIWebView(frame: self.bounds)
        webview!.delegate = self
        webview?.scalesPageToFit = true
        webview!.loadRequest(request);
    }
```

Does anyone have some insight into how I'm approaching this incorrectly? All the methods are called correctly and in the right order, but no image is shown in the `UIImageView`.

Comment: Why do you want your Image View to load a website? If image view starts loading the website, then what is the purpose of creating UIWebView? Can you be more clear on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Harsh The idea behind that was the need to 'draw' the website somewhere - or else I have the url/some html, and no idea what that actually looks like rendered. Or is it possible to get the data from the website, and then display it somehow?

Comment: The view of your webview needs to be loaded already before the loadRequest command, or in other words the webview must already exist in the parent view. Is that the case?

Comment: @Armin I don't believe that's the case, no

Comment: At which point are you adding your webview inside this imageview (as weird as this sounds)?

Comment: @Armin doesn't sound weird at all; it looks like after the image view has been created already

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Webview to the image view at some point. By this I mean, using the `addSubview` method on the imageView, and all this before calling the `loadRequest` method on the webview. Your webview needs to have a "physical" frame and exist within a parent view before you can load the content.

Comment: That makes sense. Since I'm trying to add this webview in a custom class that inherits from `UIImage`, how would I do that?